# .htaccess: excluding specific directories when working with two or more slashes in url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In short: I am working on a website where consumers can compare companies (service providers) in a several branches. Therefor we work with SEO friendly url's with max. 3 "directories": `mydomain.com/1/`, `mydomain.com/1/2/` and `mydomain.com/1/2/3`. In these url's is 1 the branch within the user can search, 2 respresentates the city and 3 defines the company name.

I've done this with the following code in my .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks  
    RewriteEngine On 

    RewriteRule ^(style|media)(/.*)?$ - [L] 

    RewriteRule index\.* index.php [L,QSA]  
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ branch.php?branch=$1&city=$2 [L,QSA]  
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ company.php?branch=$1&city=$2&company=$3 [L,QSA]  
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ branch.php?branch=$1&city=$2 [L,QSA]  
    RewriteRule ^([^/][a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ branch.php?branch=$1 [L,QSA]  
</IfModule>
```

My stylesheets are located in the directory style, and this works fine if you go to the webaddress mydomain.com or mydomain.com/1. The adresses mydomain.com/1/ and further redirects to the right filename, but keeps searching for stylesheet.css in `mydomain.com/1/style/` (or `mydomain.com/1/2/style` and so on). I know there are a lot of these questions on this site, and I tried many of them, but none of them really does what I want.

I understand if this scenario is tough one, so I thought I would make it easier (but since this lang is confusing me, I don't really know what to do now lol). So here is what I need:

- Every request has to redirect to index.php, with the given directories added as parameters. (so domain.com/1/ rewrites to `index.php?1=1` and domain.com/1/a/b rewrites to `index.php?1=1&2=a&3=b, in index.php` I will lookup which page I have to include then).
- Dirs *style* and *media* are excluded from this rule.
- Not every excisting dir or file has to be excluded, because users may not reach the dir *includes* (for example)

I hope you can help me, because I am making a huge mess of it ^^

Thanks!

Comment: Use root-relative urls. So change `<link href="style/file.css" ...` to `<link href="/style/file.css" ...`

Comment: A little late, but this helped for me. Thanks!